# catkin rename package script - Implementation, Usefulness, Others?

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've implemented a [quick script](https://github.com/eacousineau/common_scripts/blob/master/scripts/catkin_rename_package.sh) to rename catkin packages (details in the [README](https://github.com/eacousineau/common_scripts#catkin_rename_packagesh)).

Does this script seem useful enough to incorporate into any core packages?
Does anyone have any other existing solutions out there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146856/catkin-rename-package-script---implementation,-usefulness,-others?/) by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-04-01**:
The big problem with renaming a package is fixing all the references in other packages that depend on it. That is why it is best to think carefully about the name when starting out.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-01**:
In general you might want to use ${PROJECT_NAME} as much as possible in your CMake code. Then you have only two line where the package name is mentioned: in the package.xml as well as the project() in CMake.

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2014-04-01**:
@joq - Yeah, this definitely should not be used to change a package name at a whim, but it helps for an inexperienced / rushed developer (e.g. a grad student :P) who prototyped a package for internal use and wants to then distribute it with a less ambiguous name at a later date. In addition, the script is built to fix the name references in other packages - depends tags, catkin dependencies, header files, include directories, etc.

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2014-04-02**:
@Dirk Thomas - Will do, thanks! I looked at [templates/CMakeLists.txt.in](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/blob/master/src/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in), and it seems like `@{name}` is used in place of `${PROJECT_NAME}`. Would it be worthwhile to change that?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-02**:
The referenced template already uses ${PROJECT_NAME} all over the place. So I don't think anything needs to be changed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks quite neat, maybe you want to send a message to ros-users mailing list with this.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eacousineau](https://answers.ros.org/users/5276/eacousineau/) on 2014-04-01**:
Cool, will do. Thanks for the suggestion!